# How to achieve Remote Validation Using Fluent Validation as like Asp.Net MVC Data Annotation Remote validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

Asp.Net MVC provides an internal remote validation by tagging Remote attribute to respective field in your model . 
When I tag any field with Remote it generates some extra attributes to support Remote validation .

**data-val-remote="EmailID is invalid." data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.EmailID" data-val-remote-url="/Home/TestEmailID"/**

How can I achieve the same thing using Fluent Validation ?
I searched a lot in google and found one article which says to create a custom remote validator as described in below link but It's a bit difficult for me to understand as I am new to fluent validation .

http://nripendra-newa.blogspot.com/2011/05/fluent-validation-remote-validation.html

If anyone can guide me how to to create this custom remote validator along with JQuery adapter to trigger this I will be really thankful .

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code that shows where you're at will be helpful

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing what is described in this link .

http://nripendra-newa.blogspot.com/2011/05/fluent-validation-remote-validation.html

But I am not sure how to register this in App_start and more over I want to create an extension method which should accept controller validation function as an input . Controller validation function returns JSON as desribed in the article .
Please share your thoughts and suggestions .

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that actually there is no support for Remote validation in Fluent (v3).

Check [this](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/258348) thread for more information from developers of FluentValidation.

Some custom implementation [here](http://nripendra-newa.blogspot.it/2011/05/fluent-validation-remote-validation.html)